# regular expression autocomplete

Tags: java, regex, autocomplete

I have a list of sentences defined in a file.
I'd like to propose an autocomplete functionnality to the GUI's users based on the list of sentences defined in the file.

If my sentences defined in the file were strings, I would loop on the file and check if each string startsWith what the user started to type.

But the sentences in the file are regular expressions to avoid grammar mistake such as ("a"/"an").

A concrete example: in my file I have the list

- [Tt]here (is a|are) car products?
- [Tt]here (is an?|are) air products?

And the user starts to write
"There is"

I'd like to return to him

- There is a car product
- There is an air product

Apart from creating all the possible strings from the regular expression I don't know how I can achieve this.
Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Is your app a webapp? If yes, jQuery UI has an [interesting autocomplete solution](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: jquery takes a list of string, so this is not what I need

Comment: I don't think it can be done with regex.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to determine all the possible strings which could match a regular expression. esp as you appear to allow.

```
[Tt]here (is an?|are) air products?
```

could be

```
There is an air product
There is an air products
There is a air product
There is a air products
There are air product
There are air products
```

Plus all the variations with `there`

I suggest you use a different format as your regular expressions appear to filter invalid responses but doesn't define only valid responses.

Comment: @Alderath correct. I wasn't sure whether it was meant to be `an?` or `(an)?` and got myself confused. ;)